# What is difference between var [{}] and var{} in javascript and let[{}] and let {} in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is difference between `var [{}]` and `var {}` in Javascript and `let [{}]` and `let {}` in Typescript?

I am working with the two languages frequently so this is a fundamental questions I am thinking very frequently, can't wait to read your constructive comments.

**NOTE** I am not asking difference between `let` and `var`

Comment: I'm assuming the downvotes are because you just said reference the title. Hopefully people don't think it's an invalid question, because I think it's a perfectly fine question. You might want to rewrite your question body to be more specific and readable.

Comment: The question is still unclear. It seems that it is asking about the difference of creating an object and creating an array of length one with an object inside. But that is pure speculation. Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correct...

`[{}]` is an array which contains one item - an object `{}`. Later you can add more objects into this array and get like `[{}, {}]`

`{}` is just an object. Comparing with the above, this type of variable is in the array.

> What about declaration with `var` and `let`.

Actually the difference is related to the `var` and `let` which you don't ask :). It is related to their nature/behaviour, not to the `[{}]` and `{}` with `let` or `var`.

**Example**

```js
let obj = { prop: 'Prop from object' };
let arrayOfObj = [ { prop: 'Prop from array object' } ];

console.log(obj.prop);
// ------------^^^^^
console.log(arrayOfObj[0].prop);
// -------------------^^^^^ Accessing the first item in the array which is the object at first place and then to its proeprty
```

> let [{}] and let {} in Typescript?

`let` in Typescript is the same as in Javascript (ES6)

Answer (score 2):

`[{}]` is an array

`{}` is just an object.

`let` => allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope

for further reference 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

```js
function letTest() {
  let x = 1;
  if (true) {
    let x = 2;  // x value different variable
    console.log(x);  // 2
  }
  console.log(x);  // 1
}

letTest();
```

`var`  =>  Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed.

```js
 function varTest() {
      var x = 1;
      if (true) {
        var x = 2;  // x value different variable
        console.log(x);  // 2
      }
      console.log(x);  // 2
 }

 varTest();
```

//object

```js
var obj={"id":1,"name":"kalaiselvan.a"};

console.log(obj);
```

//array of object

```js
var arr=[{id:1,name:"Emile Cantero"},{id:2,name:"Suren Srapyan"},{id:3,name:"Wesley Coetzee"}]
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`[{}]` and `{}` mean the exact same thing whether it's `let` or `var`

`[{}]` is an array(`[]`), of object(s)(`{}`), `{}` is just an object.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are the symbol for arrays []
Inside an array you can have strings, numbers... and an object.
The symbol of the object is the Curly brackets {}.
So you have an Array with an Object inside it.

Answer (score 0):

`[{}]` is an array containing an object while `{}` is an object. Both are using the literal form.

`let` creates its own scope and it is not hoisted unlike `var` that has no scope and it's hoisted.

```
function testVar () {
  var a = 2;
}
```

Looks like this on runtime:

```
var a; // hoisted

function testVar () {
  a = 2;
}
```

This is not the case for `let` as it creates its lexical scope on runtime;

```
function testLet () {
  let a = 2;
}
```